# Where is xorg.conf in Kali Linux (Debian)?

Tags: xorg, kali-linux

I'm following a guide to do some screen config modifications on my Kali Linux (installed in VirtualBox on my Mac). The guide is written for Debian so I figured it would work for my Kali, but I can't locate the file `xorg.conf`. According to the guide it should be in `/etc/X11/` but it's not there on my install.

[image]

Comment: I'm not a linux user myself, but Google is telling me it should be in /etc/X11/ like you say. Did you get this distro from an official repository?

Comment: @Wutnaut yup downloaded iso from official site

Comment: Doesn't linux have a file search? Just search for xorg.conf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modern distros do not ship an xorg.conf, but let Xorg autoconfigure.  If you need to change something from the defaults, then you need to create xorg.conf yourself (usually in `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`).